# The divergence of gradient of an integral

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem, laplacian, greens-function

Let given a $ C^2(\bar{\Omega}) $ function
$$u(r)=\int_{\Omega}(\nabla f).(\nabla g))dv$$
Then how to find $ \nabla^2 u(r)? $ Can i pass the Laplace operator inside the integral? If so how could I do too? Any hint?

Comment: How does the integral depend on $r$? Isn’t $u$ just a constant?

Comment: Yes on $r$. $u(r)=\int_{\Omega}(\nabla f(r)).(\nabla g(r))dv$, where $r$ is a vector, $r=(x_1,x_2, x_3).$